# How to find what maximizes the total net profit?

Tags: linear-programming

> A meat packing plant produces $480$ hams, $400$ pork bellies and $230$ picnic hams every day; each of these products can be either fresh or smoked. The total number of hams, bellies and picnics that can be smoked during a normal working day is $420$; in addition, up to $250$ products can be smoked on overtime at higher cost. The *net* profits are as follows:
>
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
>   \hline
>     & Fresh & \mbox{Smoked on regular time} & \mbox{Smoked on overtime} \\
>   \hline
>   Hams & 8$ & 14$ & 11$\\
>   Bellies & 4$ & 12$ &7$ \\
>   Picnics & 4$ & 13$ & 9$\\
>   \hline
> \end{array}
>
> For example the following schedule yields a total net profit of $9,965$ $.
>
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
>   \hline
>     & Fresh & \mbox{Smoked on regular time} & \mbox{Smoked on overtime} \\
>   \hline
>   Hams & 165 & 280 & 35\\
>   Bellies & 295 & 70 & 35 \\
>   Picnics & 55 & 70 & 105\\
>   \hline
> \end{array}
>
> The objective is to find what maximizes the total net profit. Formulate as a Linear Programing problem in the standard form.

## My try:

$x_1, x_2,x_3$ represents hams, bellies and picnics
\begin{equation*}
     \begin{cases}
        \max C^Tx \\
        Ax  \le b\\
        x\ge 0
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \begin{cases}
        \max x_1,x_2,x_3 \\
\begin{pmatrix}
  8 & 14 & 11\\
  4 & 12 &7 \\
  4 & 13 & 9\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x_1\\
  x_2 \\
  x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}
\le\begin{pmatrix}
  480\\
  400\\
  230\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
        \forall i, x_i\ge 0
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Which is very different from the answer given by the book...

## The answer given by the book:

\begin{equation*}
     \begin{cases}
        \max 6x_1 +3x_2+8x_3+ 3x_4+9x_5+5x_6 \\
        x1 +x2  \le 480\\
        x_3+x_4\le 400\\
        x_5+x_6\le 230\\
        x_1 + x_3 + x_5\le 420\\
        x_2 + x_4 + x_6 \le 250\\ 
        \forall i,x_i\ge 0
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X1: Smoked on regular time (hams)     X2: Smoked on over time (hams)
   X3: Smoked on regular time (pork)     x4: Smoked on over time (pork)
   X5: Smoked on regular time (picnic)   X6: Smoked on over time (picnic)

Total number of hams is less than or equal to 480     (X1+X2)
Total number of pork is less than or equal to 400     (X3+X4)
Total number of picnic is less than or equal to 230   (X5+X6)

Total number of hams, bellies and picnics that can be smoked during a normal working day is equal or less than            420      (X1+X3+X5)

250 products can be smoked on overtime at higher cost  (X2+X4+X6)

Comment: Okay, So we don't include the fresh products?